# connect power bi to python with the api rest

Tags: python, azure, powerbi

i used the code bellow to connect power bi to python via the api rest using microsoft azure but whenever i run the file the url show me "This site can’t be reached"
PS: i replace the client_id and the client_secret here with **** because of privacy

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
# initialize the config parser
config= ConfigParser()
# add section to config file
config.add_section('power_bi_app')
config.set('power_bi_app','client_id','****')
config.set('power_bi_app','client_secret','****')
config.set('power_bi_app','redirect_uri','https://localhost/redirect')

# write to a config.ini file
with open(file='configs/config.ini',mode='w+') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

```
from pprint import pprint
from configparser import ConfigParser
from powerbi.client import PowerBiClient

config=ConfigParser()
config.read('configs/config.ini')

client_id = config.get('power_bi_app','client_id')
client_secret = config.get('power_bi_app','client_secret')
redirect_uri = config.get('power_bi_app','redirect_uri')


#initialize the powerbi client

power_bi_client = PowerBiClient(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    scope=['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'],
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    credentials='configs/power_bi_state.jsonc'
)
```